# Technical difference between Protractor and Selenium

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I want to build an e2e testing suite for my Angular (2+) app.

What would be the technical differences between implementing such suite using [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org) and using [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org) (e.g. using Python Selenium or Java Selenium).

Both of them are based on the [WebDriverJS](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs), but Protractor claims to be made specifically for "Angular and AngularJS applications".

So I'm not looking for opinions on which one is better, but I would rather understand what are the practical differences (e.g. in which ways is Protractor "made for Angular apps"? can it be seen as "Selenium optimised for Angular apps" and why?).

Comment: There is no `technical` difference between Protractor and Selenium. Protractor is the `.js` fork of Selenium , written in node. Also this question should be answerable with a simple google search.

Comment: @demouser123 unfortunately it is not that simple, that is why I asked

Answer (score 0):

A good question to ask yourself when you first begin to enter the world of automation testing is: "what kind of an application am I going to be writing these tests for?" From this, you can determine the optimal route for not only the framework you choose to write your tests IN, but also the way that you are going to be writing your tests, which will be extremely helpful to know about early on; rather than later.

So tell me, what does your application do? Is it data-driven? Do users need to log in to the website in order to access it's functionality? Furthermore: what IS it's major functionality?

Comment: Mostly CRUD operations on a set of entities (list, add, edit, delete) and yes, users need to log in.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, question is expired, but for anyone who reads this: try to read [this](https://www.chercher.tech/protractor/selenium-vs-protractor) or [this](https://www.gangboard.com/blog/selenium-vs-protractor/) .

Basically, if language (java, python, kotlin, c, c#, php for selenium; js, ts for protractor) is not a problem, selenium code is simpler (because there is no promise resolution) except asynchronous calls, which can be easier to handle with protractor.
Also, for AngularJS app protractor is much more suitable.

I used protractor a lot on my previous job, and only a tiny bit of python selenium. With a few hundred tests, it is a problem to wait for all of them in protractor, because they has to be executed sequentially. I've read with selenium it is possible to run them in parallel, which would benefit development time a lot.